# How can search and replace words but with confirmation using vi

Tags: linux, unix

I am having a training about the fundamentals of Unix/Linux in AT&T and we have an activity in Shell Procedures in Searching and Replacing. I have a text document that i opened in VI editor and i want to search and replace words but with each word there should be a confirmation if i will be replacing the word. How would i probably do that with "/"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option c for confirm can be used.

```
:%s/old/new/c
```